# Printing through a Samba server without recording the password in plaintext

Tags: samba, password, cups

I need to access a printer through a Samba server. In CUPS, I could make it work by entering a device location such as `smb://username:password@hostname/printer_name`. However, it would mean for my password to be retained in cleartext in a configuration file, which I would like to avoid (even though it is not accessible to regular users).

Is there a way to record my password through the KDE wallet, or to make the Samba server ask for a password everytime?

Answer (score 0):

Would it be an option to set up the samba printer on a guest account instead, so you don't need a password. You could restrict it to a set of IP addresses.

Comment: No, I have no access to the server configuration and the sysadmins want me to go through AD authentication for printing (and I don't want to store a sensitive password in cleartext).